Are games where you pretend to be something called by the name of the venue/building?
On TV, I heard when children are thinking of what game they should play, one of them said:
We will play hospitals.
From this sentence, I think that maybe the names of games in english -in which you imitate something or someone- are called by the place or building. So, I wonder if it is applicable to all other such games where a prentending to be something happens. For instance, can I say:

We will play houses. (a game where players pretend to be members of a household)
We will play schools. (a game where one pretends to be the teacher and others students)
We will play farms/zoos/forests. (a game where players pretend to be animals living in a farm/zoo/forests)

Is this the way it is?

Most of the examples are typical of children's speech, where the "game" doesn't really have any clear definition beyond "Let's pretend we are [at] XXXX" (XXXX = house, doctors & nurses, mummies & daddies,...). But many adults (Americans more than Brits, especially in "Movieland") say "Let's play ball". Where Brits might say "Let's play catch".

We also don't tend to use the plural as a label this way.  That is, if we are pretending to be a teacher and students, we would usually say "Let's play school", not "Let's play schools".

@stangdon, Thanks, this (plural form) was one of the things I have wondered, because it caught my attention she said ".....play hospitalS". Should that also be "We will play hospital?

While a lot of the examples you list are idiomatic, it's not a universal rule that kids' role-playing games (commonly referred to by generic terms like "let's pretend" or "make believe") are named after a building or premises. For example, kids in the UK say "let's play mums and dads" when pretending to be a family. That's not named after the building a family would live in. In fact, 'play house' is a term used to refer to an adult who dabbles with domestic life but doesn't commit to it.
As well as "let's play hospitals", you will also hear kids say "let's play doctors and nurses", so it's not the only way to refer to the same game.

My sister and I used to 'play schools' with her collection of dolls. They would be made to sit in rows at imaginary desks and some would be told off for talking, need to be excused, etc. By the way, I know that to the pure, all is pure, but I still might have chosen a different final example, that wording having, as it does for some, a particular meaning
